# AssertionConsumerServiceURL from AuthnRequest not from Config

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Noticed that the `Saml2AuthnResponse` `Destionation` is set based on the `relyingParty.SingleSignOnDestination` which is retrieved from a "configuration" (harcoded relyingParties array).

I think the `Destination` should be based on what is set in the `AuthnRequest` `samlp:AuthnRequest` -> `AssertionConsumerServiceURL` and use the `relyingParty` `Destination` maybe as a fallback if its missing from the `AuthnRequest`, but from what I see every `AuthnRequest` contains the ACS URL.

Or is there a reason why it is implemented this way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the security only to replay known URLs/domains. Therefore it is important to configure the `relyingParty.SingleSignOnDestination` for each relying party.

To have a dynamic response URL you can extend the code to verify that the `authnRequest.AssertionConsumerServiceUrl` starts with the value in `relyingParty.SingleSignOnDestination`.

E.g. the value in `relyingParty.SingleSignOnDestination` could be "https://somedomain.com"
and thereby accept different `authnRequest.AssertionConsumerServiceUrl` like "https://somedomain.com/auth/AssertionConsumerService" or "https://somedomain.com/acs"